# Error in installing Dash module - 'Failed building wheel for brotli'

Tags: plotly-dash

I am new to the coding world and trying to build my skills in Python as a stepping stone for Data Analytics.
I am facing a problem in installing Dash module on my local machine. The error where it is getting stuck is 'Failed building wheel for brotli'
I am using Windows 10 / Python 3.9.0 / PIP 20.2.4 / pycharm.
I have been able to successfully install plotly and while installing dash module - first I got the error of 'wheel' not installing - which got rectified by installing wheel module (pip install wheel). Later the error for dash was 'Failed building wheel for brotli'. Had tried installing using command prompt(pip) as well as PyCharm.

**Can someone please help. Below is the log that I am getting.**

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install dash
Requirement already satisfied: dash in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.17.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.12 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from dash) (4.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-compress in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask_compress-1.8.0-py3.9.egg (from dash) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-seasurf in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from dash) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.12->dash) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.12->dash) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.12->dash) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.12->dash) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: retrying>=1.3.3 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (1.3.3)
Collecting brotli
  Using cached Brotli-1.0.9.zip (510 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.12->dash) (1.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: brotli
  Building wheel for brotli (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-t7_2ranf'
       cwd: C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jna0pqh\brotli\
  Complete output (18 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating bin
  creating bin\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying python\brotli.py -> bin\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_brotli' extension
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\common
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\dec
  creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\enc
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/include -Ic:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include /Tcc/common/constants.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c/common/constants.obj
  constants.c
  C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jna0pqh\brotli\c\common\./platform.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for brotli
  Running setup.py clean for brotli
Failed to build brotli
Installing collected packages: brotli
    Running setup.py install for brotli ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lnmkirsr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\brotli'
         cwd: C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jna0pqh\brotli\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating bin
    creating bin\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying python\brotli.py -> bin\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_brotli' extension
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\common
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\dec
    creating bin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c\enc
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/include -Ic:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include /Tcc/common/constants.c /Fobin\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\c/common/constants.obj
    constants.c
    C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jna0pqh\brotli\c\common\./platform.h(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Arinjay Jaiswal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jna0pqh\\brotli\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Arinjay Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lnmkirsr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\arinjay jaiswal\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\brotli' Check the logs for full command output.
```